# How can I prove $A − A(A + B)^{−1}A = B − B(A + B)^{−1}B$ for matrices $A$ and $B$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

The [matrix cookbook](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ebonner/courses/2018s/csc338/matrix_cookbook.pdf) (page 16) offers this amazing result:

$$A − A(A + B)^{−1}A = B − B(A + B)^{−1}B$$

This seems to be too unbelievable to be true and I can't seem to prove it. Can anyone verify this equation/offer proof?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

\begin{align}
A - A(A+B)^{-1}A & = A(A+B)^{-1}(A+B) - A(A+B)^{-1}A \\ &= A(A+B)^{-1}(A+B - A)\\ &= A(A+B)^{-1}B \\ &= (A+B - B)(A+B)^{-1}B \\ &= (A+B)(A+B)^{-1}B - B(A+B)^{-1}B \\ &= B - B(A+B)^{-1}B
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

You may simply put $X=A+B$ and show that
\begin{aligned}
A-AX^{-1}A
&=(X-B)-(X-B)X^{-1}(X-B)\\
&=(X-B)-(X-2B+BX^{-1}B)\\
&=B-BX^{-1}B.
\end{aligned}